# CURL Reccuring Requests

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP CURL to send some request to third party server with API. as following code

```
    <?php
    $txt="test";
    $url="END POINT";
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    "POST DATA");

    $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);
    ?>
```

When the third party server down or slow to response CURL sends multiple requests to the server making my request duplicate, how to stop this?

Comment: When are you making this request exactly, on a page-load, a fixed interval, etc.? If it is when loading a page, you could run it periodically on the server, store the result locally and use that for your page for example.

Comment: it happen on button click, when third party server response fast there was no issue, it happen only occasions, i think CURL retry the request once a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

If the requests are on button click. The problem might be that users click on the button, when there is no answer, they started clicking o pushing F5 and make the request several times.
You could disable the button click when the request is sent, then it is enabled when the request is finished.

Sorry I don't put this on a comment. I cannot add comments yet.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I will add this validation and wait for results.